# File can not be executed from Java

Tags: java, execute

When i try this code, it seems as executed but it is not executed.

The process builder can find the executable file. System writes the println commands.

I found some example codes but my executable file is not in same folder with java file.

```
private static void executeOneFile(String folderPath) {
    Process p;
    String exePath = path + "\\" + folderPath + "\\";
    try {
        p = new ProcessBuilder(exePath +  "myFile.exe").start();
        //p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myFile.exe", null , new File(exePath) );

        System.out.println("p is running");
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("p ended");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens then? No errors or exceptions? How do you know the .exe didn't run?

Comment: can you show how you set the `path` variable? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No error and no exception. Exe should create an output file but it does not. When i double click manually it creates.

Comment: I wrote path variable manually. I printed the path there is no problem . When i change it i take exception: Cannot find...

Comment: what dir are you expecting the created file to go in to?  Its working dir may not be where you expect (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory())

Comment: the exe file crate output in same folder. I use: 
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("idarc2d_7.0.exe");
   pb.directory(new File(exePath));
   System.out.println(pb.directory().getAbsolutePath() + pb.directory().getName());
   p = pb.start();
   I got : CreateProcess error=2, System can not find the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code above:

1. You don't handle stdin/stdout properly. So maybe there is an error but you won't see it because you're not reading the output of the child process.
2. Next, it's always a good idea to close the child's `stdin` with `p.getOutputStream().close()` to make sure it doesn't hang waiting for input.
3. Lastly, the current directory of the process is the same as that of the Java VM. So if you use relative paths to write the file, it will end up somewhere but rarely where you expect. Pass the absolute path of the file to your child process to make sure the output goes where it should.

Comment: Thank you. exe file wait for more input. so i should close the stream. I used this lines and fixed the problem :
         Process process = pb.start();
         process.getInputStream().close();
         process.waitFor();
         process.getOutputStream().flush();
         process.getOutputStream().close();

Comment: You got that wrong. First, you have to close **process.getOutputStream()** because this is **Java's** output stream which will be the child processes **input**